# Exclude a category slug on pagination

Tags: php, categories, pagination, slug

I'm a beginner of wordpress ... I'm creating my first template and I would like to exclude the category "portfolio" from pagination. I tried in every way, but I managed to do just the opposite, browse through posts in the same category.

Do you have any suggestions?
thank you so much

this is the code. I want to browse all posts, except posts with "portfolio" category.

```
<div class="row pagination pt-5">
  <div class="col-5 no-gutter">
      <p class="text-left "><?php previous_post_link(); ?></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5 no-gutter">
      <p class="text-right"><?php next_post_link(); ?></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „excluding from pagination”? Do you want to exclude posts from this category, so they won’t appear on index?

Comment: I want that in the pagination of single.php the posts of the portfolio category never appear. I want to browse all posts except those in the portfolio category.

Comment: But single.php displays only one post. What “pagination” are we talking about then? Do you mean prev/next post link?

Comment: Yes exactly the prev/next post link. Sorry for my English..

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/300998/edit) to add in the code that isn't working. This might help us figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Change Query Vars ( filter `parse_query` ) - using [Taxonomy Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) or `post__not_in` if you going preselect posts from category and put them to cache so you can skip db calls sometimes